# Error when doing vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, radix, vagrantfile

I get this error when I do a `vagrant up` :

```
anr@anr-Lenovo-G505s ~ $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /home/anr/base
```

This is the Vagrantfile I have:

```
 # -*- mode: ruby -*-
 # vi: set ft=ruby :
 Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
   config.vm.box      = 'precise32'
   config.vm.box_url  = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box'
   config.vm.hostname = 'bootcamp'
   config.ssh.forward_agent = true

config.vm.provider 'vmware_fusion' do |v, override|
  override.vm.box     = 'precise64'
  override.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64_vmware.box'
end

config.vm.provider 'parallels' do |v, override|
  override.vm.box = 'parallels/ubuntu-12.04'
  override.vm.box_url = 'https://vagrantcloud.com/parallels/ubuntu-12.04'

# Can be running at background, see https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels/issues/39
v.customize ['set', :id, '--on-window-close', 'keep-running']
end

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

 config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
   puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests'
   puppet.module_path    = 'puppet/modules'
 end
```

end

This is my machine setup:

```
 vagrant -v     Vagrant 1.6.2
 VirtualBox     4.3.2
 Linux Mint 15 Olivia Cinammon
```

Answer (score 44):

I was having this problem. I was creating the folder, and using the following commands:

```
vagrant init
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64
vagrant up
```

and getting the error about downloading the remote file.

Try this:

```
create a folder,
cd folder
vagrant init hashicorp/precise64 (or whatever vm you want to run)
vagrant up
```

Hopefully this resolves your issue

Comment: Thanks! I was spending countless hours trying to fix this issue.

Comment: doesnt work for me.. Instead of looking for `/my/path/to/foo` it now is looking for `/my/path/to/foo/foo`

Comment: From a year ago, I have lost the hope to install homestead , due to consecutive errors , but with your trick , Now i had homestead working . thx alot @Martin

Comment: Hmm, funny because if you just walk through the tutorial on the vagrant site you'll will end up right here with this problem as it leads you through those exact steps: create folder, go to folder, vagrant init, vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64, vagrant up -> error.  The additional parameter to init creates a .vagrant subfolder with the additional pieces that seem to be necessary to make this work.  The very first getting started page has you run vagrant init hashicorp/precise64, but it doesn't tell you where to run it and the following pages lead you down this hole, without explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying problem is that your VM machine is mislabeled. I also realize you are targeting "precise32", but i'm using "base" as an example here.

if you were to navigate to:

```
~/.vagrant.d/boxes
```

you would see something like this:

```
$ ls -la
```

drwxr-xr-x   4 some_user  staff  136 Oct 22 09:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x  10 some_user  staff  340 Oct 22 09:41 ../
drwxr-xr-x   4 some_user  staff  136 Jun 29 13:23 hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/

that last line is telling you that you have only one box, and its the precise32 box.

however, assuming you setup a default Vagrant setup like so:

```
$ cd ~/src/vagrant/myvm
$ vagrant init
```

if you look inside the Vagrant file created for you:

```
$ vim Vagrant
```

you will see the following output:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "base" 
end
```

note that it is looking for the box named "base"! So what I did is:

```
$ cd ~/.vagrant.d/boxes
$ cp -R hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32 base
$ cd ~/src/vagrant/myvm
$ vagrant up
```

and then you can go back and delete the "hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32" box as it is now a duplicate.

Of course, you could have done this another way and renamed

```
config.vm.box = "base"
```

to whatever your box is called, but i found the former way better because if you wish to create a second vm based on the default box, then you would face the same problem. So its better to rename the box, instead of renaming each time you "vagrant init".

Comment: go to .vagrant.d/boxes/ and change folder "laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead" name to "base". Worked for me with this.

Answer (score 1):

if you renamed the default name "base"

try it:

**vagrant init "your box name"**

It's work for me.

[also see](https://github.com/astaxie/go-best-practice/blob/master/ebook/zh/01.2.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by simply install vagrant hostupdater

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on git bash:

1. $ vagrant box list 
     the following results : 
        --$ vagrant box list  
        --2017/07/03 00:30:19 launcher: detected 32bit Windows installation
        --ubuntu/trusty64 (virtualbox, 20170619.0.0) 
   copy boxname : ubuntu/trusty64
2. $ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
3. $ vagrant up

Answer (score 0):

downgraded your vagrant version to 1.9.2. Download to MSI file for Windows from [this link.](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/1.9.2) 
and reboot your PC. Enable virtualization in the bios setting.
Then again try with vagrant up command. 
This will definitely work.

Answer (score -1):

Run this command on git bash:

```
cp /mingw64/bin/curl.exe /c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/curl.exe
```

with me work

Comment: Worked pretty awesome for me. Error was 
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/boxes/centos-7.2/versions/2.2.9/providers/virtualbox.box
    default:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.